# Can I use shapeless to return the same arity of HList as passed HList?

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

Here is an example. I'm trying to wrap some external api that accepts and returns the same arity of `List`:

```
def externApi(args: List[Int]): List[String] = args.map(_.toString)
```

I thought this was a good excuse to learn shapeless as it seems like something that `HList` would be able to do.

```
def foo(args: HList): HList = ???
```

How can I encode in type that passed `HList` and returned `HList` are of the same arity?

Comment: perhaps `Sized` can help: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/sized.scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @stew's comment, you can use `Sized` to enforce an equal arity between the lists.

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.sized._

def externApi[N <: Nat](args: Sized[List[Int], N]): Sized[List[String], N] =
    args.map(_.toString)
```

Usage:

```
scala> externApi(Sized[List](1, 2, 3, 4))
res0: shapeless.Sized[List[String],shapeless.nat._4] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> res0 foreach println
1
2
3
4
```

I'm far from a shapeless expert, so I don't know if there is a way to do this with an `HList`, but it seems like your collections are homogeneous anyway.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you